# get calculation from two tables related with a third table

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

i have this table

```
     table1
|  id  |  name  |
|  1   |  axe   |
|  2   |  bow   |
|  3   |  car   |
|  4   |  dart  |
```

and these two tables

```
        table2                                        table3
|  t1_id  |  number  |                        |  t1_id  |  letter  |
|  1      |  5       |                        |  1      |  a       |
|  1      |  6       |                        |  1      |  b       |
|  1      |  2       |                        |  1      |  c       |
|  2      |  2       |                        |  2      |  a       |
|  2      |  2       |                        |  2      |  c       |
|  2      |  3       |                        |  2      |  r       |
|  3      |  8       |                        |  3      |  y       |
|  3      |  3       |                        |  3      |  i       |
|  3      |  1       |                        |  3      |  a       |
|  4      |  8       |                        |  4      |  a       |
|  4      |  9       |                        |  4      |  b       |
|  4      |  10      |                        |  4      |  c       |
```

where in it **t1_id** is the **table1 id**

what i want to do is to get all **table1** records having **table3 letters a b c** and the avg of their numbers like this order by the **letter_count** **DESC** first then by the **avg_numbers** **DESC**

```
|  id  |  name  |  letter_count  |  avg_number   |
|  4   |  dart  |  3             |  9            |
|  1   |  axe   |  3             |  4.3333333333 |
|  2   |  bow   |  2             |  2.3333333333 |
|  3   |  car   |  1             |  4            |
```

the query i expected to work properly was http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69086b/3/0

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.name, 
  COUNT(t3.letter) AS letter_count, 
  AVG(t2.number) AS avg_number

FROM 
  table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id

LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3
    ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
      AND t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

GROUP BY
  t1.id

ORDER BY
  letter_count DESC,
  avg_number DESC
```

but numbers are totally different and in accurate but the order is correct

i don't want to get the **letter_count and  avg_number** values but i just want to order by them but their values are worrying me with the query performance

i wouldn't notice this weird values because my actual query is

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.name

FROM 
  table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id

LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3
    ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
      AND t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

GROUP BY
  t1.id

ORDER BY
  COUNT(t3.letter) DESC,
  AVG(t2.number) DESC
```

which only gives me proper ordery

```
|  id  |  name  |
|  4   |  dart  |
|  1   |  axe   |
|  2   |  bow   |
|  3   |  car   |
```

but after checking the values i was surprsied by the **letter_count** do i just ignore the values and it wouldn't affect the performance in my big table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating over two different dimensions.  This causes a Cartesian product.  One way to fix this is to aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.letter_count, t2.avg_number
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT t2.t1_id, AVG(t2.number) as avg_number
      FROM table2 t2
      GROUP BY t2.t1_id
     ) t2
     ON t2.t1_id = t1.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t3.t2_id, COUNT(t3.letter) as letter_count
      FROM table3 t3
      WHERE t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
      GROUP BY t3.t2_id
     ) t3
     ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
ORDER BY t3.letter_count DESC, t2.avg_number DESC;
```

Comment: can i use my query if i won't need the `letter_count` and `number_avg`, would it be faster in this case? and the execution plan of it seems to be better then the derived tables that i don't understand and its row counts of `12` twice as here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69086b/7/0

Answer (score 0):

On the third table, IN-SELECT Subquery.

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.name, 
  (
    SELECT count(letter)
    FROM  t3 
      where  t3.t1_id = t1.id
    ) as lettercount,
  AVG(t2.number) AS avg_number

FROM 
  table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
```